# Are the electrons in a quantum hall edge state entangled?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-entanglement, quantum-hall-effect, quantum-teleportation

I am reading the paper on Quantum Energy Teleportation by Yusa, Izumida and Hotta([This article](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2203)), and it seems that they are assuming that the quantum hall edge state is a quantum correlated state, which I understand as it being an entangled state.

How can all the electrons in the edge state be entangled?

Or have I misunderstood the assumptions of the article?

Comment: I don't know this subject, but the bulk QH state is a many-electron wavefunction, and in the paper they say there is a current at the edge, so the edge state must be a quantum state describing the evolving charge density at the edge. And I don't see a problem with e.g. the expected charge density at different points on the edge being quantum-correlated.

Comment: It will be nice to define "entangled" in order for other to answer the question. In general, every ground states are correlated, which you may view as entangled. Since every ground state is entangled, so it is not very useful in this context.